# Adding a method to all classes that implement an interface

Tags: java, interface

There are several classes (which I can't edit) which implement an interface, is it possible to add a method that only calls methods defined in the interface to each class that implements that interface?

(without java 8)

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't believe so.  Such a method would have to realized in the concrete class as a real method, but without access to the classes themselves you can't do that.

You might create subclasses of each, and all those subclasses could implement you new interface with the new method.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I get you right but if classes A, B, C, ... implement an interface I and you can not edit A, B, C, ... and want to add a method you propably could just extend each class with a new subclass and each subA, subB, subC and so on could implement the new method...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8 and can modify the interface, then yes:

```
interface Face {
    Object existing();

    default Object additional() {
        return "Hello " + existing() + "!";
    }
}
```

Otherwise, no, you cannot. Java does not have a feature like Javascript prototypes, C# extension methods, etc at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do what you are asking, not without resorting to byte code manipulation anyway.

Perhaps AOP would help, you could add a point cut to the target methods of the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a `static` method that takes in the interface type and calls the methods:

```
interface Fooable
{
    void foo();
}


public class FooableExtensions
{
    public static void doSomethingToFooable( Fooable f /*, other parameters*/ )
    {
        f.foo();
    }
}
```

It doesn't have the fancy syntactic-sugar that C# extension methods provide, but it should do the trick.